# Right ALT key not working as meta key in emacs

Tags: emacs, archlinux

I have launched emacs (`emacs -Q`) in the console(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>). The "left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key" is 
working whereas the "right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key" is not working. How to fix the problem. I am running emacs on archlinux

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you trying to achive? What is your expected behaviour when pressing "right alt key" and what are you getting?

Comment: i expect the "right alt key" also to act as the Meta key as in ubuntu

Comment: When i press "Right ALT key + x", x is printed in the current buffer as thought there is no effect on the "Right ALT key".

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is controlled by the keyboard layout you are using. In the layout that you are using, the left alt is `Meta`, whereas the right alt is `Alt-graphic` which allows you to enter accentuated character. **Change your keyboard layout** to one not using the right alt as `Alt-graphic`

Comment: In ubuntu "Right ALT-x" will prompt M-x in the mini buffer, How to get the same behaviour

Comment: It has to do with the keyboard layout that you are using.

Comment: It is very nice explanation of _why_ it is happening, but does not explain how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is described here:
http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/04/fixing_the_righ.html

It needs some modifications though (see item 3.2 below).
Otherwise one would not be able to type anything in current console after the first press of `[Right Alt]`.
If this happened to you, switch to other console (e.g. `[Ctrl+Alt+F2]`) and restore old keymap.

Here is the brief description of the modified solution:

1. Save current keymap to file:
   `dumpkeys >> mykmap`
   and make a backup of it:
   `cp mykmap oldkmap`
2. Capture `[Right Alt]` keycode using `showkey` command. Let's assume it is `100`.
3. Edit `mykmap`:

   1. Find the corresponding line:
      `keycode 100 = AltGr`
      and change it to:
      `keycode 100 = Alt`
   2. If the next line (or one of the next lines) is:
      `alt keycode 100 = Compose`
      remove it.
4. Load new keymap:
   `loadkeys mykmap`
5. Make the changes permanent (e.g. add the last command to ~/.bashrc).

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround. Hit `Esc` key to activate the alt key as meta in emacs.
So a command like `M-v` becomes `Esc M-v`